# Win10 Arc 10.6.1 pip refusing most installs

Tags: python, pip, arcgis

Windows 10 64 bit
ArcGIS 10.6.1 & Python 2.7

I use a previous answer to avoid failed SSL errors.

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

I simply cannot get much to install through pip, including the pip --upgrade pip. There are different errors for different packages so nothing really consistent. A check with SciPy says it is installed and up to date all in white text. Almost anything else returns red and yellow error text.

Some clearly state 2.7 on their sites but apparently not for ArcGIS Python 2.7. For example, CNTK states 2 and 2.7 on this page

https://pypi.org/project/cntk/

but gives this error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cntk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cntk

Am I simply wasting my time. Do ArcGIS Python 2.7 installs simply not like working with other free software packages? Are there really no AI packages for Python 2.7?

Have you tried using Arc Python 2.7 with third party packages? Did it work?